# How do I get an array value instead of reference from ObjectMapper in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I am trying to get a result from an API response and am able to map everything except for columnHeaders, which is an array of ColumnHeaders.  I am instead getting a reference to an array.  The code is below.

Response Class

```
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty("searchApiFormatVersion")
    private String searchApiFormatVersion;

    @JsonProperty("searchName")
    private String searchName;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("columnHeaders")
    private ColumnHeader[] columnHeaders;

public Response(String searchApiFormatVersion, String searchName, String description,
                    ColumnHeader[] columnHeaders) {
        this.searchApiFormatVersion = searchApiFormatVersion;
        this.searchName = searchName;
        this.description = description;
        this.columnHeaders = columnHeaders;
    }

    public Response(){

    }

    public String getSearchApiFormatVersion() {
        return searchApiFormatVersion;
    }

    public void setSearchApiFormatVersion(String searchApiFormatVersion) {
        this.searchApiFormatVersion = searchApiFormatVersion;
    }

    public String getSearchName() {
        return searchName;
    }

    public void setSearchName(String searchName) {
        this.searchName = searchName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    
    public ColumnHeader[] getColumnHeaders() {
        return columnHeaders;
    }

    public void setColumnHeaders(ColumnHeader[] columnHeaders) {
        this.columnHeaders = columnHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response{" +
                "searchApiFormatVersion='" + searchApiFormatVersion + '\'' +
                ", searchName='" + searchName + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", totalRowCount=" + totalRowCount +
                ", returnedRowCount=" + returnedRowCount +
                ", startingReturnedRowNumber=" + startingReturnedRowNumber +
                ", basetype='" + basetype + '\'' +
                ", columnCount=" + columnCount +
                ", columnHeaders=" + columnHeaders +
                '}';
    }
}
```

ColumnHeader class

```
public class ColumnHeader {

    @JsonProperty("text")
    private String text;

    @JsonProperty("dataType")
    private String dataType;

    @JsonProperty("hierarchy")
    private int hierarchy;

    @JsonProperty("parentName")
    private String parentName;

    @JsonProperty("isEntity")
    private Boolean isEntity;

    @JsonProperty("isEset")
    private Boolean isEset;

    public ColumnHeader(String text, String dataType, int hierarchy, String parentName, Boolean isEntity, Boolean isEset) {
        this.text = text;
        this.dataType = dataType;
        this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
        this.parentName = parentName;
        this.isEntity = isEntity;
        this.isEset = isEset;
    }

    public ColumnHeader(){

    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }

    public void setDataType(String dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public int getHierarchy() {
        return hierarchy;
    }

    public void setHierarchy(int hierarchy) {
        this.hierarchy = hierarchy;
    }

    public String getParentName() {
        return parentName;
    }

    public void setParentName(String parentName) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
    }

    public Boolean getEntity() {
        return isEntity;
    }

    public void setEntity(Boolean entity) {
        isEntity = entity;
    }

    public Boolean getEset() {
        return isEset;
    }

    public void setEset(Boolean eset) {
        isEset = eset;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ColumnHeader{" +
                "text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", dataType='" + dataType + '\'' +
                ", hierarchy=" + hierarchy +
                ", parentName='" + parentName + '\'' +
                ", isEntity=" + isEntity +
                ", isEset=" + isEset +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Service Class

```
public class BudgetEffortResponseService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Response.class);

    public Response getResponseFromStringJsonApiResponse(String stringJsonResponse) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); //Used to map objects from JSON values specified in Award under @JsonProperty annotation
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        JSONObject stringJsonResponseTurnedIntoJsonObject = new JSONObject(stringJsonResponse);

        logger.info("stringJsonResponseTurnedIntoJsonObject: " + stringJsonResponseTurnedIntoJsonObject);

        return objectMapper.readValue(stringJsonResponseTurnedIntoJsonObject.toString(), Response.class);

    }
}
```

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EtlApplication {

    public static final String API_USERNAME = System.getenv("API_USERNAME");
    public static final String API_PASSWORD = System.getenv("API_PASSWORD");
    public static final String API_PREFIX = System.getenv("API_PREFIX");
    public static final String API_PATH = System.getenv("API_PATH");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, JsonProcessingException {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EtlApplication.class);
        logger.info("--------------------Starting process--------------------");

        AwardRepository awardRepository = new AwardRepository();
        AwardService awardService = new AwardService();
        ApiResponseRowService apiResponseRowService = new ApiResponseRowService();
        ApiResponseRepository apiResponseRepository = new ApiResponseRepository();
        BudgetEffortResponseService budgetEffortResponseService = new BudgetEffortResponseService();

        Date startDateForApiPull = new GregorianCalendar(2023, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1).getTime();
        Date endDateForApiPull = new GregorianCalendar(2023, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 2).getTime();

        logger.info("============Starting BudgetEffort API pull from Huron===============");

        HttpResponse<String> budgetEffortHttpResponse = apiResponseRepository.getHttpResponseFromApi(startDateForApiPull,
        endDateForApiPull, 1, -1, API_PREFIX, API_PATH,
        API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD);

        logger.info("BudgetEffortHttpResponse: " + budgetEffortHttpResponse);

        logger.info("============End of BudgetEffort API pull from Huron===============");

        //Get body of http response string
        String budgetEffortResponseString = budgetEffortHttpResponse.body();
        logger.info("BudgetEffortResponseString: " + budgetEffortResponseString);

        Response budgetEffortResponse = budgetEffortResponseService.getResponseFromStringJsonApiResponse(budgetEffortResponseString);

        logger.info("BudgetEffortResponse: " + budgetEffortResponse);

        logger.info("--------------------End of process--------------------");
    }

}
```

The response.  I'm noticing that I'm getting the reference to the array for columnHeaders and not the values.  How would I get the values?  Thank you.

```
BudgetEffortResponse: Response{searchApiFormatVersion='1.0', searchName='Personnel Details for Authorized allocations on Active Awards', description='', columnHeaders=[Lcom.example.etl.entity.budgetEffort.ColumnHeader;@7a7471ce}
```

Comment: In order to print array you need to use `Arrays.toString()` method. For example: `", columnHeaders=" + Arrays.toString(columnHeaders) +`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you get is ok. And also the Array is good. The line

```
logger.info("BudgetEffortResponse: " + budgetEffortResponse);
```

uses an indirect cast to String of the Object budgetEffortResponse. In this case all `toString()` methods of the objects are called. What you need to do in order to print out the Objects is to implement/add the `toString()` method in the class `com.example.etl.entity.budgetEffort.ColumnHeader`

### Update:

As the toString method is already implemented, the above is partially wrong. But there is a way to use a setting of the ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// pretty print
String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(budgetEffortResponse);
logger.info("BudgetEffortResponse: " + json);
```

Comment: `ColumnHeader.toString()` is already implemented.

Comment: You're right in that the array is valid.  I get the expected response when I add logger.info("Column Headers Array: " + Arrays.toString(budgetEffortResponse.getColumnHeaders())); to the main method. I'm having issues with a similar array and thought that the fact that I was getting a reference to the array instead of the values was the issue. I will update the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer - the update should work.